# HTML Agility Pack is not working when filtering by class Name

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to scrape some data from a commercial site. I am trying to drill down to a specific class, However I am having difficulty drilling down and filtering.

```
   var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var html =  await httpClient.GetStringAsync(Url);
     
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
    
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body");
        var divs = nodes.Descendants("div").Where(x => x.HasClass("srp-main srp-main--isLarge"));
```

I am getting null for "divs". Where am I going wrong?

My ultimate goal is to drill down to div with class name = s_item__info clearfix. So help with that would be appreciated.

[image]